# Any APIs for getting current Call Divert status (from network) in IOS?

Tags: ios4

Any APIs for getting current Call Divert status (from network) in IOS ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's absolutely no access to telephony status.

(Access is likely available with jailbreaking.)